# Python поменять значение многомерного словаря, используя список с ключами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, есть словарь:

```
dict = {'key1':{'key2':{'key3':'foo'}}}
```

И есть список с ключами, а так-же новое значение:

```
keys = ['key1','key2','key3']
new_value = 'bar'
```

Как с помощью функции поменять значение с **foo** на **bar** используя ключи из массива?

Пример:

```
change_dict(dict, keys, new_value)
```

Стоит учитывать, что длина пути может меняться.

Comment: my_dict[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = new_value

Comment: ... и называть словарь зарезервированным именем `dict` - плохая  идея

Comment: @strawfog В вопросе было указано, что длина массива с путём может меняться. На счёт dict- данное название я использовал только для примера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {'key1':{'key2':{'key3':'foo'}}}

keys = ['key1','key2','key3']
new_value = 'bar'

item = data
for key in keys[:-1]:
    item = item[key]

item[keys[-1]] = new_value

print(data)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не могли бы вы объяснить работу этого алгоритма. Не очень понимаю где именно изменяется data

Comment: @Vlaffi здесь имя item последовательно указывает сначала на саму data, а потом последовательно на всё более вложенный словарь вплоть до самого внутреннего. Именно самый внутренний словарь только у нас и меняется, а data напрямую мы не меняем.